Upon creating navigation drawer, the activity/ scroll view beneath it is not working
I have created navigation drawer on an already working activity. I moved some buttons from top to navigation drawer. Now navigation drawer is working fine. It slides and click listener is also working but the activity is not working. drawer closes on clicking but on the activity nothing is clickable. Below is the code attached:
Main activity
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="com.example.fooddelivery.Activities.MainAdminActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolBarRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_grad"
        android:padding="10dp"
        >
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileIv"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_grey"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/orange"
            app:civ_border_overlay="true"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profileIv"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rec03"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="0dp">
            <!--Service Providers-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tabSPTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rec04"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Service Providers"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <!--Orders-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tabUsersTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Users"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
        <!--Service providers UI-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/SPRL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolBarRL">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/shopsRv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/row_shop" />    
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/usersRl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolBarRL">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/usersRv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:reverseLayout="true"
                app:stackFromEnd="true"
                tools:listitem="@layout/row_all_users" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <include
        layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

Header
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_grey"
        android:contentDescription="Header image"
        android:id="@+id/profileIv"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/nameTv"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Email"
        android:id="@+id/emailTv"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="0321-1234567"
        />
</LinearLayout>

Toolbar
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appL">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
     </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>

Navigation drawer
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context="com.example.fooddelivery.Activities.MainAdminActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/navView"
app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
app:menu="@menu/navigation_seller_main">

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


Attaching a screenshot or a gif of the problem would be more helpful.

Looks like, The problem might be in the activity code(java/kotlin) and not the UI. Please provide the complete code to understand and help you solve the issue.

Nah, the given layouts explain the described behavior. The <DrawerLayout> one is <included> as the last item the main one, and it covers everything, which is why touch events stop working for the stuff underneath. The main content needs to go inside the <DrawerLayout> too, not under it. The <DrawerLayout> should be the root in your setup. Unfortunately, the only place I can find in the official stuff that still describes DrawerLayout is: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/ui#add_a_navigation_drawer. Note where the main content <FragmentContainerView> is.

According to the material components documentation for modal navigation drawer use the following template:
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    ...
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- Screen content -->
        <!-- Use app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to fit below top app bar -->

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        ...
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

